# deferring an ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a bit of js code on one of my pages that uses ajax to load some page elements.  These happen at the very top of the page and unfortunately slow down loading of the rest of the page.  I was wondering if there is a way to defer this so it loads after the page has loaded.

Here is the code I am using and it is located right before the closing body tag:

```
function countrySnippet() {
      $.ajax({
          url: '/country_snippets.php?sites=<?php echo json_encode($jam_sites); ?>&disabled=<?php echo json_encode($array_disabled); ?>&no_cat=<?php echo json_encode($category_disabled); ?>&hide=<?php echo $hide_overlay; ?>&use_id=<?php echo $use_id; ?>&snippet=<?php echo $display_country_snippet; ?>&title_top=<?php echo $snippet_title_top; ?>&title_bottom=<?php echo $snippet_title_bottom; ?>&theme=<?php echo $theme_detail['
          select_theme ']; ?>&code=<?php echo $country_code; ?>&region=<?php echo $country_region; ?>&thumbs=<?php echo $snippet_number_thumbs; ?>&size=<?php echo $settings_detail['
          index_thumbs_size ']; ?>',
          type: "get",
          beforeSend: function() {
            $('.ajax-load-snippet').show();
          }
        })
        .done(function(data) {
          $('.ajax-load-snippet').hide();
          $("#country-snippet").append(data).hide().fadeIn(1000);
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          $('.ajax-load-snippet').hide();
        });
    }
    countrySnippet();
```

Comment: You can use `$(document).ready(function(){countySnippet();});` and write your deferred code inside the anonymous function.

Comment: @KamalSingh thank you for your response.  I'm really not good with javascript so I'm not entirely sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @KamalSingh,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function countrySnippet() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/country_snippets.php?sites=<?php echo json_encode($jam_sites); ?>&disabled=<?php echo json_encode($array_disabled); ?>&no_cat=<?php echo json_encode($category_disabled); ?>&hide=<?php echo $hide_overlay; ?>&use_id=<?php echo $use_id; ?>&snippet=<?php echo $display_country_snippet; ?>&title_top=<?php echo $snippet_title_top; ?>&title_bottom=<?php echo $snippet_title_bottom; ?>&theme=<?php echo $theme_detail['
        select_theme ']; ?>&code=<?php echo $country_code; ?>&region=<?php echo $country_region; ?>&thumbs=<?php echo $snippet_number_thumbs; ?>&size=<?php echo $settings_detail['
        index_thumbs_size ']; ?>',
        type: "get",
        beforeSend: function() {
          $('.ajax-load-snippet').show();
        }
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        $('.ajax-load-snippet').hide();
        $("#country-snippet").append(data).hide().fadeIn(1000);
      })
      .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        $('.ajax-load-snippet').hide();
      });
  }
  countrySnippet();
});
```